# Laravel 5 Form Request Attribute nice names not working with custom validator

Tags: validation, laravel, request, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In one of my form requests I have the following code that changes the names of the input fields for validation messages:

```
   public function attributes(){

        return [
            'title' => 'topic title',
            'content' => 'post content'
        ];

    }
```

Now I want to add custom validation rules, so I created a custom validation service:

```
class Validation extends Validator{

    public function validateFoo($attribute, $value, $parameters){

        return $value == 'foo';

    }

}
```

Then I created a validation service provider and added this boot method:

```
public function boot(){

    Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
    {
        return new Validation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    });

}
```

I then add this to the providers array in app/config/app.php:

```
  'App\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider',
```

Now all this works well and I can use my custom validation rule in the form request as expected. The problem is the nice names I set for the attributes earlier revert back to their old names so instead of getting something like 'The post title field is required.' I get 'The title field is required.'. If I remove the above entry from the providers array, then I get the nice names as expected, but then I can't use my custom validation rule. I am aware I can see these globally in a language file, but I'd rather do it like this. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Instead of doing the above, if I just add the following code into the AppServiceProvider class, then I get the expected attribute names, but I'd prefer to do it the first way as it's cleaner:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        return $value == 'foo';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to use your resources/lang/en/validation.php file for that purpose, you could change your ValidationServiceProvider's boot function to

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes)
        {
            return new ValidatorExtended($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes);
        });
    }
```

Notice that I added the additional $attributes parameter. Then you can set the "nice" names in your FormRequest Classes like you did before.

```
   public function attributes(){

    return [
        'title' => 'topic title',
        'content' => 'post content'
    ];

   }
```

Comment: Where do you add that boot function? I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: you would add this in your custom validation service provider

Comment: You don't need the boot code anymore. It works out of the box with the attributes function.